# How to build external cache for tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to figure out how to write a proper input_fn. I've rebuild a keras UNet implementation, using Tensorflow Estimators and Datasets. It is working, but it is much slower than Keras implementation.
My Input pipeline read files directly from the SSD while Keras implementation was loading the whole DataSet to memory.

I would like to do the same in DataSets, unfortunately the cache build by `ds.cache()` is cleared on each interruption to `estimator.train`.  I have to interrupt it to validate the model since I'm trying to use only one GPU.

I had a look on the implementation of `Dataset.cache` and I guess that the cache is bound to the graph that holds the Dataset, and this graph is freed each time the training is interrupted.

What options do I have so that my input pipline stays in tensorflow graphs? I would like to avoid passing the whole training data back and forth between python and tensorflow.

Can I use tensors from one graph in another? So I could create an external (to Estimator's API) graph with my input_fn and then somehow use it in a graph created by estimator.train.

Something along this lines:

```
train_graph = tf.Graph()
with training_graph.as_default():
    train_get_next = input_fn(training_set, ...) () # tensor returned by it.get_next()

def train_input_fn_with_ext_cache():
    batch = # some how obtain result of train_get_next 
    return batch

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn_with_ext_cache,  max_steps=3000)
eval_spec = ...

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```